# xarray: best way to "insert" a time slice into a dataset or dataarray

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, python-xarray

I have a 3-dimensional `xarray` dataset with the dimensions `x`, `y`, and `time`. Assuming I know that there's a missing observation at timestep `n`, what would be the best way to insert a timeslice with no-data values?

Here's a working example:

```py
import xarray as xr
import pandas as pd

x = xr.tutorial.load_dataset("air_temperature")

# assuming this is the missing point in time (currently not in the dataset)
missing = "2014-12-31T07:00:00"

# create an "empty" time slice with fillvalues
empty = xr.full_like(x.isel(time=0), -3000)

# fix the time coordinate of the timeslice
empty['time'] = pd.date_range(missing, periods=1)[0]

# before insertion
print(x.time[-5:].values)

# '2014-12-30T18:00:00.000000000' '2014-12-31T00:00:00.000000000'
#  '2014-12-31T06:00:00.000000000' '2014-12-31T12:00:00.000000000'
#  '2014-12-31T18:00:00.000000000']

# concat and sort time
x2 = xr.concat([x, empty], "time").sortby("time")

# after insertion
print(x2.time[-5:].values)

# ['2014-12-31T00:00:00.000000000' '2014-12-31T06:00:00.000000000'
#  '2014-12-31T07:00:00.000000000' '2014-12-31T12:00:00.000000000'
#  '2014-12-31T18:00:00.000000000']
```

The example works fine, but I'm not sure if that's the best (or even the correct) approach.

My concerns are to use this with bigger datasets, and specifically with dask-array backed datasets.

Is there a better way to fill a missing 2d array?
Would it be better to use a dask-backed "fill array" when inserting into a dask-backed dataset?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might consider using xarray's [`reindex`](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.Dataset.reindex.html) method with a constant `fill_value` for this purpose:

```py
import numpy as np
import xarray as xr

x = xr.tutorial.load_dataset("air_temperature")
missing_time = np.datetime64("2014-12-31T07:00:00")
missing_time_da = xr.DataArray([missing_time], dims=["time"], coords=[[missing_time]])
full_time = xr.concat([x.time, missing_time_da], dim="time")
full = x.reindex(time=full_time, fill_value=-3000.0).sortby("time")
```

I think both your method and the `reindex` method will automatically use dask-backed arrays if `x` is dask-backed.